# Kill/Yank (cut/paste) in ZSH

Tags: linux, command-line, emacs, zsh

I use zsh and have the Emacs keybindings set up for it. I'd love to have it replicate *all* my regular Emacs text manipulation commands. One which I miss is the Kill/Yank keys. It would be nice if I could select text (using <kbd>C-SPC</kbd> - this works) and then do something like a `kill-region` (<kbd>C-w</kbd> - This right now deletes the previous word). The yank (<kbd>C-y</kbd>) works fine and I can even even cycle through them using <kbd>M-y</kbd>.

Does anyone have such a setup working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A simple `"\C-w": kill-region` in my `.inputrc` file binds the key to the function I want.

---

*Update:* Spoke too soon. The above only does it for applications that use the readline libraries. Zsh uses its own `zle`. The way to configure similar behaviour is to stick `bindkey "\C-w" kill-region` into your `.zshrc`

Comment: You might want to keep `^W` and bind `kill-region` to `^X` to keep the original behavior and still be able to cut stuff out.